# How can I make my chat filter block symbols in swear words? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a chat filtering bot, and people are bypassing the bot with symbols such as underscores, periods, and a bunch of other symbols. Does anyone know a way to block all of these that are in swear words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use a regular expression, using `re`, combined with the characters in the `string` module.

Here's an example:

```py
import re
import string

symbols = string.punctuation + string.digits + string.whitespace
letters = string.ascii_letters

with open("path/to/blacklisted/words.txt") as file:
    blacklist = file.read().split('\n')

for word in blacklist:
    regex_match_true = re.compile(fr"[{symbols}]*".join(list(word)), re.IGNORECASE)
    regex_match_none = re.compile(fr"([{letters}]+{word})|({word}[{letters}]+)", re.IGNORECASE)
    if regex_match_true.search(message.content) and regex_match_none.search(message.content) is None:
        # Do something here
```

In this regular expression, an optional group is created of `symbols` and inserted between letters of the `word` variable. This is a basic layout and likely will not catch all of blacklisted words or it may catch too many. You will likely have to do lots of testing and experimentation in order to create a regular expression that fits your need.

**Edit**: The second regular expression checks if the bad word being searched is found with letters preceding or succeeding the bad word itself (no special characters between letters).

The problem that now arises it that if there is a word with a space in between, but with letters on the end(s), the regular expressions will match that pattern. For example, if the word being searched was "word" and the message contained the phrase "two rd.", the message would be flagged. The results are improved, but there are still issues.

Comment: You were right about that code, it blocks words with swear words such as 'class'.

Comment: Yes, it is an issue. I did some more experimentation and I will update my answer to try to avoid matching words such as 'class'.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have been looking for an answer to this for a month now lol

Comment: Also, there was an unmatched ')' at the end of `regex = re.compile(fr"[{symbols}]*".join(list(word)), re.IGNORECASE))`

Comment: I'm now getting a `regex is not defined` error. Do you know why?

Comment: Whoops! That is my error, but I believe I have fixed it.

Comment: You fixed it :)

Comment: And this code was the answer I was looking for! Thanks!